# access to parent from a child object

Tags: javascript

i am trying to figure out how the code below works. Can somebody explain what does it mean when it says " create an uber property that points to the parent's prototype object." What exactly does it mean when it says  "this.constructor.uber" points to parent's prototype? i've been scratching my head for a while now. i would be really thankful if somebody could explain what's happening in function Shape().

```
function Shape() {}
// augment prototype
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function () {
    var result = [];
    if (this.constructor.uber) {
        result[result.length] = this.constructor.uber.toString();
    }
    result[result.length] = this.name;
    return result.join(', ');
};


function TwoDShape() {}
// take care of inheritance
var F = function () {};
F.prototype = Shape.prototype;
TwoDShape.prototype = new F();
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
TwoDShape.uber = Shape.prototype;
// augment prototype
TwoDShape.prototype.name = '2D shape';

function Triangle(side, height) {
    this.side = side;
    this.height = height;
}
// take care of inheritance
var F = function () {};
F.prototype = TwoDShape.prototype;
Triangle.prototype = new F();
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
Triangle.uber = TwoDShape.prototype;
// augment prototype
Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';
Triangle.prototype.getArea = function () {
    return this.side * this.height / 2;
}

var my = new Triangle(5, 10);
my.toString()
```

Output: `"shape,2Dshape,Triangle"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript inheritance, there is no support for accessing a `super` method, so what I can see here with uber, is having access to its parent methods.
Name it parent as following:
`TwoDShape.parent = Shape.prototype`

That way you can have direct access to a parent property: `TwoDShape.parent.name` should return `'shape'`.

What `toString()` is actually doing here, is:

```
var result = []; //declare an array
if (this.constructor.parent) { //if there is a parent prototype
    result[0] = this.constructor.parent.toString(); //set the 0 position of result with the return value of parent's toString() method.
}
result[result.length] = this.name; //set the position (0 or 1, if we had a parent it will be 1, otherwise 0) with the current name.
return result.join(', '); //return the names joined with a comma
```

Note that I changed the `uber` to `parent` so its more readable. the first assignment of result will always be 0, so it was not necessary the call to `result.length`.

What the calls would return for each object?:
`Shape.toString();`: `'shape'` (there's no parent)
`TwoDShape.toString();`: `'shape, 2D shape'` (`'shape'` for the call to `Shape.toString();`, and `'2D shape'` for its own name, joined).
`Triangle.toString();`: `'shape, 2D shape, Triangle'` (`'shape, 2D shape'` for the call to `TwoDShape.toString();`, and `'Triangle'` for its own name, joined).

Comment: thanks for the reply Pablo. one thing that i didn't understand is "this.constructor.parent.toString()". for instance when we do: Shape.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.name;}; it will simply call toString() method and return the current object's name. but in this scenario, where and how does "this.constructor.parent.toString" return the value?

Comment: @ReemaJoshi In my example, I replaced `uber` with `parent` so it's more readable for you. I would suggest you to read [Understanding JavaScript Prototypes.](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) "The prototypical inheritance mechanism is internal and non-explicit. When object a is asked to evaluate property foo, JavaScript walks the prototype chain (starting with object a itself), checking each link in the chain for the presence of property foo. If and when foo is found it is returned, otherwise undefined is returned."